# Golden section bandwidth seach in GWR always returning nearly all neightbors

Tags: knn, geographically-weighted-regression, bandwidth

I'm running binary GWR models in MGWR and GWR4, and regardless of the optimization criterion (AICc, BIC, CV) for adaptative KNN, the softwares are always choosing N-1 nearest neighbors, or close enough to that. Same for issue for fixed bandwidth.

If this is a problem when dealing kernel functions for GWR models, can anyone let some light on possible reasons why this is happening and how to improve it?

I want my models to represent well both spatial dependency and spatial heterogeneity, and I'm unsure if having too many neightbors is bad in GWR models. For reference, one dataset has 86 observations, the other has 645.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article below helped me understand better this topic.

FOTHERINGHAM, A. S.; YU, H.; WOLF, L. J.; OSHAN, T. M.; LI, Z. On the notion of ‘bandwidth’ in geographically weighted regression models of spatially varying processes. International Journal of Geographical Information Science, p. 1-18, 2022.

To answer my own previous question, as requested by Vince:

This might happen from weak spatial dependence in the data or weak explanation from the variables used. Plus, it might also arise if you're not inputting the coordinates as they should are (spherical or projected). It's nothing wrong with a kernel itself, and might arise from any kernel function used.

Large bandwidth is a parameter that might give valid perspective, but it needs to be analyzed together with other metrics, such the improvements on AICc and adjusted percent deviance explained, when compared with the non-spatial linear regression.

So to improve it check if your data input is correct, and check again for spatial dependence for each variable. However, keep in mind that some data simply isn't adequate for GWR, and a stationary spatial regression or non-spatial linear regression should be used instead.

Also, while spatial non-stationarity should always be tested for GWR models, it's indispensable for cases with high bandwidth and/or when the performance of the GWR model isn't much better compared to the non-spatial linear regression. If at least one of the variables is stationary, you should apply a semi-parametric GWR.

As a final note, for binary GWR models (GWLR), you can't use CV for bandwidth comparison, since it relies on residuals. Instead use AICc or BIC.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/250510)

Answer (score 0):

Having too many neighbors in a GWR model is not necessarily a bad thing, it could mean that the model is not finding any local relationships in the data. So it defaults to using n-2 nearest neighbors as its bandwidth, which essentially renders it a global model.
I see that you're running the models on GWR4 which is the version for Windows OS. I would recommend that you utilize the latest version of [PySal's MGWR distribution](https://mgwr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

Comment: Hello, Victor. Yes, after reading Fotheringham et al (2022), I see it the same way you do. But finding N-1 or N-2 for KNN bandwidth might be a sign that a spatial global model could provide a better fit.

Once I have more time I'll try GWmodels in R. Replying this so to share the alternative with you.

FOTHERINGHAM, A. S.; YU, H.; WOLF, L. J.; OSHAN, T. M.; LI, Z. On the notion of ‘bandwidth’ in geographically weighted regression models of spatially varying processes. International Journal of Geographical Information Science, p. 1-18, 2022.